# Creating an invite in a GuildCreate event

Tags: discord.js

So I was trying to make my bot send me a DM to every server it joins but I keep getting the API error: Unkown Channel

My code:

```
bot.on("guildCreate", async guild => {
guild.channels.first().createInvite().then(inv =>
bot.users.get(ownerID).send(`I have been added to **${guild.name}** | ${inv.url}`)
)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is your problem. I have made the same mistake a few months ago, here's how to fix it.

Since you are using discord.js version 11, `guild.channels` is indeed a Collection, which you can use .first() on. In this case, you can't do that.

Here's my workaround:

```js
bot.on("guildCreate", async guild => {
    var channel;
    guild.channels.forEach(c => {
        if (c.type === "text" && !channel) channel = c;
    });
    channel.createInvite({ maxAge: 0 }).then(inv => bot.users.get(ownerID).send(`I have been added to **${guild.name}** | https://discord.gg/${inv.code}`));
});
```

This basically loops through each channel and finds a valid TextChannel to create an invite.

Hope this helps.